# Terracotta tile grout problems

Tags: tile, grout

I have a handyman installing terracotta tile in a kitchen remodel I'm doing. Most of it is looking pretty good, but the grout is having difficulty in some places; the grout was put down in two layers. Is this something that can be cleaned up, then maybe float an epoxy grout over the top? What's the best way to make it look good and last?

[image: Grout that is pulling out]

Comment: What is the width of the grout line?

Comment: The best way is to carefully remove the loose grout and regrout.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of or done grout in two layers. It will lose much of it's strength. If the grout line is greater than 1/8", hopefully sanded grout was used. The grout in your picture looks as if it was prematurely dried and cracked as a result.

To fix this, get a grout saw and remove the grout down to the thinset. Mix up a small batch according to directions and re grout the area with a float. Clean the residue off the tiles and keep the grout moist for hours depending on manufacturer's direction.

There are epoxy grouts that are great but using them to patch areas wouldn't give the same effect.

Seal your new, and old grout according to directions on the grout package.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds like what we were thinking. All the terracotta was eyeballed without spacers, and the width is around 1/8" at the base. These are handmade terracotta tiles I ordered from Mexico, so there are variations, and using spacers was pretty much impossible. The width at the top is greater than the width at the bottom, as the edges curve.